# MRUnit for Parquet

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, parquet, mrunit

I am trying to test my driver with `MRUnit` and my `MapDriver` format is `MapDriver <LongWritable, Group, ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>` I have found the correct serialization for `KeyValue` but cannot find one for `Group` and I get the following error.

```
    Group group = sfg.newGroup()
    parquetMapDriver.withInput(new LongWritable(), group);
```

> No applicable class implementing Serialization in conf at
>   io.serializations: class
>   org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple.SimpleGroup

I am currently setting `io.serializations` like so

```
    parquetMapDriver = MapDriver.newMapDriver(parquetMapper);
    conf = parquetMapDriver.getConfiguration();
    conf.setStrings("io.serializations", conf.get("io.serializations"),
    MutationSerialization.class.getName(),
    KeyValueSerialization.class.getName(),
    WritableSerialization.class.getName(),
    ResultSerialization.class.getName());
```

Where I can find the serialization for Hadoop's Group Class?

Comment: Solved by downgrading mrunit versions in my pom.xml

Comment: How did you get serialization for org.apache.parquet.example.data.Group working?